Evaluating the integral in an integral representation of the sum that is the Fourier series for $e^{ax}$
I aim to evaluate the following sum through an integral representation of it:
\begin{align*}
& \frac{\sinh a \pi}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{a - i n} e^{i nx}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{\sinh a\pi}{a \pi} + \dfrac{2 a \sinh a \pi}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{a^2+n^2} \cos (nx) - \dfrac{2 \sinh a\pi}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n n}{a^2+n^2} \sin (nx)
\end{align*}
Through detailed a calculation (presented below), I have found that this sum can be expressed as:
\begin{align*}
2 \frac{\sinh a\pi}{\pi} Im \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\end{align*}
(although, I haven't justified a step in the calculation where you interchange a summation and integration). My question is: How do you evaluate the integral in this expression? Knowing that the sum is actually the Fourier series for $e^{ax}$ on the interval $[-\pi, \pi)$, we anticipate that the integral should yield:
\begin{align*}
Im \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du = \dfrac{ \pi e^{ax}}{2 \sinh a \pi} - \frac{1}{2a}
\end{align*}
on the interval $[-\pi, \pi)$ and be periodic in $x$ with period $2 \pi$. This is the target result we aim to achieve through the evaluation of the integral.
Calculational details: Expressing the sum as an integral
We write
\begin{align*}
& \frac{\sinh a \pi}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{a - i n} e^{i nx}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\sinh a \pi}{\pi} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{i a + n} i e^{i nx} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{-i a + n} i e^{-i nx} + \frac{1}{a} \right)
\nonumber \\
& = i \frac{\sinh a \pi}{\pi} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{i a + n} e^{i nx + i n \pi} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{-i a + n} e^{-i nx - i n \pi} \right) + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = - 2 \frac{\sinh a\pi}{\pi} Im \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ia + n} e^{i n (x+\pi)} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} du + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = - 2 \frac{\sinh a\pi}{\pi} Im \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{in(x+\pi)} e^{-(n+ia)u} du + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = - 2 \frac{\sinh a\pi}{\pi} Im \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n (u-ix-i\pi)} e^{-iau} du + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = - 2 \frac{\sinh a\pi}{\pi} Im \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{-ia u} }{ e^{u - i x - i \pi} - 1} du + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = 2 \frac{\sinh a\pi}{\pi} Im \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{-ia u} }{ e^{u - i x} + 1} du + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = 2 \frac{\sinh a\pi}{\pi} Im \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du + \frac{\sinh a \pi}{a \pi}
\end{align*}
You would need to justify interchanging the summation and integration, which I haven't done. You can write:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty |Im (-1)^n e^{inx} e^{-(n+ia)u}| du & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty |(-1)^n \sin (nx+a) e^{-nu}| du 
\nonumber \\
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-nu} du
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty
\end{align*}
Therefore, the series of integrals may diverge, but it could also be finite. Without further analysis, we cannot definitively conclude whether the series of integrals converges or diverges. Thus, we cannot apply Fubini's theorem to justify the interchange of summation and integration based solely on this inequality.
It is unclear whether or how the dominated convergence theorem can be applied to justify the interchange of summation and integration.

I got stuck on this question. I've now realised if I modify a previous solution method, I can get it to work. I don't know if this is the simplest solution. I would be interested to get feedback off people how to make steps of the derivation rigorous where interchanges were made. I've now used this summation method and another summation method here to sum up various Fourier series and thereby reconstructing the function the Fourier series represents. I don't know if there are any possible applications though.
Define $I(b) = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^{u/b} + e^{ix}} du$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^{u/b} + e^{ix}} du & = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^{u/b} + e^{ix}} du 
\nonumber \\
& = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} (-u/b^2) e^{u/b}}{ (e^{u/b} + e^{ix})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = - \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-iab u} ue^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du  \qquad  (*)
\end{align*}
where in the last line I have made the substitution $u \mapsto bu$. Note that:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^{u/b} + e^{ix}} du db = \left[ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^{u/b} + e^{ix}} du \right]_0^1
= \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du
\end{align*}
Integrating both sides of $(*)$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du & = - \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-iab u} u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du db
\nonumber \\
& = - \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 e^{-iab u} db \dfrac{ e^{ix} u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = - \frac{i}{a} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} (e^{-ia u} - 1) e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du
\end{align*}
Taking the complex conjugate of the above result, substituting $u \rightarrow -u$, and rearranging, we get:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{-ix} e^{ia u} }{ e^u + e^{-ix}} du & = \frac{i}{a} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{-ix} (e^{ia u} - 1) e^u}{ (e^u + e^{-ix})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{i}{a} \int_{-\infty}^0 \dfrac{ e^{-ix} (e^{-ia u} - 1) e^{-u}}{ (e^{-u} + e^{-ix})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{i}{a} \int_{-\infty}^0 \dfrac{ e^{ix} (e^{-ia u} - 1) e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du
\end{align*}
Note:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( - \frac{d}{du} \dfrac{e^{ix}}{ e^u + e^{ix}} \right) du = \left[ - \dfrac{e^{ix}}{ e^u + e^{ix}} \right]_{-\infty}^\infty = 1  .
\end{align*}
Using the above results, we have:
\begin{align*}
Im \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du & = - \frac{i}{2} \left( \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du - \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{-ix} e^{ia u} }{ e^u + e^{-ix}} du \right)
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} (e^{-ia u} - 1) e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du - \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du - \frac{1}{2a}  \qquad  (**)  .
\end{align*}
In order to evaluate the integral in the last line of  $(**)$, consider the rectangular contour $C$ in the figure

and the contour integral
\begin{align*}
\oint_C \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia z} e^z}{ (e^z + e^{ix})^2} dz
\end{align*}
whose integrand has pole at $ix + i \pi$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$. The integral along the vertical edges vanishes as:
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \dfrac{e^{ix} e^{-ia (u+iv)} e^{(u+iv)}}{(e^{u+iv} + e^{ix})^2} =
\begin{cases}
      e^{ix} e^{-ia (u+iv)} e^{- (u+iv)} & u \rightarrow \infty \\
      e^{-ix} e^{-ia (u+iv)} e^{(u+iv)}  & u \rightarrow - \infty \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
\oint_C \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia z} e^z}{ (e^z + e^{ix})^2} dz = (1 - e^{a 2 \pi}) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du
\end{align*}
which rearranged
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du & = \frac{\pi i}{a (1 - e^{a 2 \pi})} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia z} e^z}{ (e^z + e^{ix})^2} dz
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi i}{a (1 - e^{a 2 \pi})} Res_{z=ix+i\pi} \left[ \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia z} e^z}{ (e^z + e^{ix})^2} \right]
\end{align*}
For $- \pi \leq x < \pi$ there is a pole in rectangular contour at $z_0 = i x + i \pi$. We wish to expand the integrand in powers of $z-z_0$ about pole $z_0$. First note:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = \frac{e^{-2 z_0}}{(e^{z-z_0} - 1)^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2} - \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\end{align*}
Then note:
\begin{align*}
- \dfrac{e^{z_0} e^{-ia z} e^z}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = - e^{-z_0}  \dfrac{ e^{(-ia + 1) z_0 + (-ia + 1) (z-z_0)} }{ (z-z_0)^2 } + e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(-ia + 1) z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\nonumber \\
& = - e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(-ia + 1) z_0} [1 + (-ia + 1) (z-z_0) + \cdots] }{ (z-z_0)^2 } + e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(-ia + 1) z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\nonumber \\
& = - \dfrac{ e^{-ia z_0} }{ (z-z_0)^2 } - \dfrac{ -ia e^{-ia z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\end{align*}
Combining everything
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} e^u}{ (e^u + e^{ix})^2} du
& = \frac{\pi i}{a (1 - e^{a 2 \pi})} Res_{z=ix+i\pi} \left[ \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia z} e^z}{ (e^z + e^{ix})^2} \right]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi i}{a (1 - e^{a 2 \pi})} \cdot ia e^{a (x+\pi)}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi e^{ax}}{e^{a \pi} - e^{- a \pi}}  .
\end{align*}
Using this in $(**)$ we finally have:
\begin{align*}
Im \int_0^\infty \dfrac{ e^{ix} e^{-ia u} }{ e^u + e^{ix}} du & = \dfrac{ \pi e^{ax}}{2 \sinh a \pi} - \frac{1}{2a}  .
\end{align*}
